# Master theorem with $f(n) = n\log(\log n)$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I have a question related to algorithm time complexity and master theorem.

How to solve this master theorem $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n\cdot \log(\log(n))$?

We have 3 cases:

> [image: aaa]

I don't know which one to use and why.

Comment: I don't think the Master Theorem applies here because $n\cdot \log \log n$ applies to none of those cases.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Why cannot we use case 2? Is not _**k>=0**_ ?

Comment: That says $\log^k n$ which is $\log$ to a power. This is a composition of $\log$s.

Comment: And is there any way to (mathematically) prove that we cannot use Master Theorem for this example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relation can not be used with the Master Theorem because $f(n)=n\log \log n$ does not meet any of the cases.

- Is $f(n)=O(n^{1-\epsilon})$? No, because $n\log \log n$ grows faster than $n$.
- Is $f(n)=\Theta(n\cdot\log^k n)$? No, because $n\cdot\log\log n$ grows slower than $n\log n$.
- Is $f(n)=\Omega(n\cdot\log^k n)$? No, because $f(n)=o(n\log n)$ and $n\log n=o(n\cdot\log^k n)$.

This isn't really a rigorous proof, but that's the logic behind why the Master Theorem doesn't apply here. In general, the Master Theorem only applies to polynomials or polylogarithmic complexities and $n\cdot\log\log n$ are neither of those.